The uniqueness of constant scalar curvature metrics in the conformal class of a hyperbolic metric
In the sphere, the constant scalar curvature metric may not be unique within the conformal class of a metric. What happens in a closed hyperbolic $n$-manifold ($n>2$)? Can the fact that the Yamabe constant is negative guarantee that a constant scalar curvature of $−n(n−1)$ is unique within the conformal class of a metric?

Your question has a positive answer, and follows from the following more general result:

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $\mathcal{C}$ a conformal class with negative Yamabe invariant. Any two constant scalar curvature metrics are homothetic to one another.

Proof: Since $\mathcal{C}$ has negative Yamabe constant, there is a negative constant scalar curvature metric $g \in \mathcal{C}$; write $s_g \equiv c < 0$. Suppose $\tilde{g} \in \mathcal{C}$ is another constant scalar curvature metric with $s_{\tilde{g}} \equiv \tilde{c}$.
There is a function $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that $\tilde{g} = e^{2\varphi}g$. The scalar curvatures of the two metrics are related by the formula
$$s_{\tilde{g}} = e^{-2\varphi}(s_g + 2(n-1)\Delta_g\varphi - (n-1)(n-2)|d\varphi|_g^2)$$
where $\Delta_g = d^*d + dd^*$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator (the adjoint is taken with respect to $g$).
If $p \in M$ is a global maximum of $\varphi$, then $(d\varphi)(p) = 0$ and $(\Delta_g\varphi)(p) \geq 0$, so
$$\tilde{c} = s_{\tilde{g}}(p) = e^{-2\varphi(p)}(s_g(p) + 2(n-1)(\Delta_g\varphi)(p)) \geq e^{-2\varphi(p)}s_g(p) = e^{-2\varphi(p)}c.$$
If $q \in M$ is a global minimum of $\varphi$, then $(d\varphi)(q) = 0$ and $(\Delta_g\varphi)(q) \leq 0$, so
$$\tilde{c} = s_{\tilde{g}}(q) = e^{-2\varphi(q)}(s_g(q) + 2(n-1)(\Delta_g\varphi)(q)) \leq e^{-2\varphi(q)}s_g(q) = e^{-2\varphi(q)}c.$$
Since $\varphi(p) \geq \varphi(q)$ and $c < 0$, we have $e^{-2\varphi(p)}c \geq e^{-2\varphi(q)}c$ and hence
$$\tilde{c} \geq e^{-2\varphi(p)}c \geq e^{-2\varphi(q)}c \geq \tilde{c}.$$
Therefore, all the inequalities are equalities. In particular, we have $\varphi(p) = \varphi(q)$, so $\varphi$ is constant and hence $\tilde{g}$ and $g$ are homothetic. $\square$
Returning to your question, let $(M, g)$ be a compact hyperbolic $n$-manifold and consider the conformal class $\mathcal{C} = [g]$. By the above, any other constant scalar curvature metric $\tilde{g} \in \mathcal{C}$ is of the form $\tilde{g} = \lambda g$ for some constant $\lambda > 0$ and has scalar curvature $s_{\tilde{g}} = \frac{1}{\lambda}s_g = -\frac{1}{\lambda}n(n-1)$. Therefore, the only constant scalar curvature metric in $\mathcal{C}$ with scalar curvature $-n(n-1)$ is the hyperbolic metric.

The above result also works if the Yamabe constant of the conformal class is zero. The same proof shows that $s_{\tilde{g}} = \tilde{c} = 0$ and hence $\Delta_g\varphi = \frac{1}{2}(n-2)|d\varphi|_g^2 \geq 0$, so $\varphi$ is subharmonic and hence constant by the maximum principle.
If the Yamabe constant is positive, then there can be constant scalar curvature metrics which are not homothetic, see this question. There is still uniqueness up to homothety if the conformal class contains an Einstein metric, except if it is the conformal class of the round metric on a sphere. This is known as Obata's Theorem, see this question.

It’s worth mentioning the work of Dan Pollack as well, since he showed that for any metric with positive Yamabe constant, it is possible to find a small (non-conformal) deformation where the solution to the Yamabe problem has many solutions.
